# Difference between two similar if loops in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have two codes which should perform the same thing but in the first, I am not getting the result but in the second one I am getting output

```
    if (Method == "EMM" ):
        if ((Loan_Obligation/12)+EMI) !=0:
            DSCR_Post = EBITDA_EMM/((Loan_Obligation/12)+EMI) 
        else:
            0
    elif (Method != "EMM" ):
        if ((Loan_Obligation/12)+EMI) !=0:
            DSCR_Post = EBITDA/((Loan_Obligation/12)+EMI)
        else:
            0
```

and other one is:

```
    if (Method == "EMM"):
        DSCR_Post = EBITDA_EMM/((Loan_Obligation/12)+EMI) if ((Loan_Obligation/12)+EMI) !=0 else 0
    else:
        DSCR_Post = EBITDA/((Loan_Obligation/12)+EMI) if ((Loan_Obligation/12)+EMI) !=0 else 0
    print('DSCR_Post:',DSCR_Post)
```

Can someone help me what is the difference between the two codes

Comment: Where's the loop?

Comment: The second chunk of code has a print statement which will always be called.

Comment: what is your else ? it should be `else: DSCR_Post=0` in first

Answer (score 0):

In your first code snippet, you are not assigning the 0 to `DSCR_Post` as you do in the second. Modify as follows:

```
if Method == "EMM" :
    if (Loan_Obligation / 12) + EMI !=0:
        DSCR_Post = EBITDA_EMM / ((Loan_Obligation / 12) + EMI) 
    else:
        DSCR_Post = 0  # the 0 has to be assigned!
else:  # you do not need a condition here! It can either be equal or not, no third state possible.
    if (Loan_Obligation / 12) + EMI !=0:
        DSCR_Post = EBITDA / ((Loan_Obligation / 12) + EMI)
    else:
        DSCR_Post = 0
print('DSCR_Post:',DSCR_Post)
```

Which can be simplified to the following:

```
ebid = EBITDA_EMM if Method == "EMM" else EBITDA
DSCR_Post = 0  # 0 will be overwritten if ...
if (Loan_Obligation / 12) + EMI != 0:
    DSCR_Post = ebid / ((Loan_Obligation / 12) + EMI) 
print('DSCR_Post:',DSCR_Post)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried doing the same code in R(Shiny). I just want to check if this is correct:

Comment: EMIP<- reactive({ input$FLAP*((1 + Int()*input$Tenure)/input$Tenure) })
  # proposed loan amount from dscr to loan amount
  DSCR_Post<- reactive({ 

  if ( input$MU == "EMM"){ 
       if ((input$EMIM/12) + EMI() != 0){
      EBITDA_EMM()/((input$EMIM/12) + EMI())
         }else{
         {0}}
    } else if (input$MU != "EMM"){
      if ((input$EMIM/12) + EMI() != 0){
        EBITDA()/((input$EMIM/12) + EMI())
    } else {0}} })

Comment: Actually i need to do the same logic in R. But I am unable to do so

Comment: @GeetanjaliBisht That does not change the fact that *I cannot read it* xD. Does the code above not solve the issue?

Comment: if ( input$MU == "EMM"){ 
       if ((input$EMIM/12) + EMI() != 0){
         DSCR_Post = EBITDA_EMM()/((input$EMIM/12) + EMI())
         }else{
         {DSCR_Post = 0}}
    } else if (input$MU != "EMM"){
      if ((input$EMIM/12) + EMI() != 0){
        DSCR_Post = EBITDA()/((input$EMIM/12) + EMI())
    } else {DSCR_Post = 0}} })

Comment: Proper indentation is not coming when I am trying to write the code